# How do i add a PDF version map into the spotfire application?

Tags: spotfire

Trying to workout how i take a pdf map and present it in spotfire so i can mark out sections using latitude and longitude? I am looking to plot points on this map.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! We need more information from you in order ot help. Please see here on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A PDF may as well be an image. There is no spatial metadata associated with it, and Spotfire doesn't have a way to analyze and image and rectify points on it. Nothing does, that I know of.